# How i can make this grid be scrollable?

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

```
private Core.Controls.Model.Grid CreateOfferGrid()
    {
        Core.Controls.Model.Grid offerGrid = new PopupGrid("ProjectOfferCalculationForm");

        offerGrid.ItemsSource = "ProjectRealization";
        offerGrid.ItemType = "IAngeboten";
        offerGrid.BindTo = "ProjectRealization";
        offerGrid.AllowAdd = true;
        offerGrid.Group = "PR_ANG_OFFER";
        offerGrid.AllowDelete = true;
        offerGrid.AllowEdit = true;
        offerGrid.IsInline = false;
        offerGrid.Advanced = true;
        offerGrid.KendoPopUp = true;

        offerGrid.Columns.Add(new GridColumnDefinition("Id", "Id", ColumnType.Text, false));
        offerGrid.Columns.Add(new GridColumnDefinition("Number", ProjectsModuleDefinition.ProvideOffersNumberColumnName(),    ColumnType.Text, true) { Width = "20" });

        return offerGrid;
    }
```

[grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxozi.png)

As you see in pictrue there is no scroll. I dont have any idea how make this scroll visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the scroll bar with these settings:

```
PageSize = 50;
VerticalScrollBarMode = ScrollBarMode.Visible;
VerticalScrollableHeight = 300;
```

This was found [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T584480/gridview-how-to-set-enable-scrolling) by the way.